# Clear text from a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, textarea

I'm writing text on a jPanel: when I press a button it shows text about that button, when i press another one shows text about that one and so on...

The text area is created like this:

```
    JTextArea log = new JTextArea(1,20);
    log.setMargin(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
    log.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(log);

    add(logScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

When I display some text with:

```
log.append("No file path specified");
```

I'm not able to delete the previous text. For esample if I press twice the same button i get the string

> "No file path specifiedNo file path specified"

I'm not able to clear the text area to display only the new string. I've tryed with:

```
log.removeAll();
```

before the log.append() But didn't work.

Comment: You're appending text, what else would you expect? That's different than *setting* text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use either `log.setText(null)` or `log.setText("")`, same thing

Rather the appending text, you should try `log.setText("No file path specified");`, which will replace the current contents with the new `String` (Thanks Dave)

You might like to take some time to read through [Using text components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) for more details

Answer (score 2):

try setText from JTextComponent super class

`setText("")`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29